# How to convert dates with different format to weekdays

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[01-Sep and 02-Sep should appear as FRI & SAT while as per the formula I am using

`=TEXT(DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(L1,4)), VALUE(MID(L1,4,2)), VALUE(LEFT(L1,2))),"ddd")`,

weekdays appeared perfect for dates starting 13-Aug till 31-Aug but not for the first 12 days on each month.
I do beleive that the format on my desk is by default mm/dd/yyyy but the report I am generating is dd/mm/yyyy and would like to get the weekdays, I tried to change the format but was not possible

[image: I need support please]

Here is what I am getting
[image]

And here is what I am expecting
[image]

Comment: What did you expect to return with `VALUE(LEFT(L1,2))` actually? You are probably taking the first two digits in the numeric representation of the value in `L1`. The same with `MID()` and `RIGHT()`. Since Excel will auto convert text representing dates when they are valid (note that `1/09/23` is valid in either notation, this will mess up your formula.

Comment: Are they dates? If the values are dates you could just do `=TEXT(L1, "ddd")`

Comment: To wrap up my 1st comment; start by making sure all inputs are actually string values representing a date, not a combination.

Comment: I already used =TEXT(R1, "ddd") but it works for the first 12 days for the month but not for other days like 31/08/2023

Comment: Moreover the system understand 01/09/2023 that is related to 09-Jan-2023 while it should be 01-Sep-2023

Comment: @FayezSoweid, that is exactly what is mentioned before. So make sure they are all string input's instead.

Comment: Here is the result in excel 20/08/2023 21/08/2023 22/08/2023 23/08/2023 24/08/2023 25/08/2023 26/08/2023 27/08/2023 28/08/2023 29/08/2023 30/08/2023 31/08/2023 1/09/23 2/09/23
20/08/2023 21/08/2023 22/08/2023 23/08/2023 24/08/2023 25/08/2023 26/08/2023 27/08/2023 28/08/2023 29/08/2023 30/08/2023 31/08/2023 Mon Thu
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Sat Sun

Comment: 20/08/2023 21/08/2023 22/08/2023 23/08/2023 24/08/2023 25/08/2023 26/08/2023 27/08/2023 28/08/2023 29/08/2023 30/08/2023 31/08/2023 1/09/23 2/09/23
20/08/2023 21/08/2023 22/08/2023 23/08/2023 24/08/2023 25/08/2023 26/08/2023 27/08/2023 28/08/2023 29/08/2023 30/08/2023 31/08/2023 Mon Thu
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Sat Sun

Comment: @FayezSoweid very sorry to say, you just made your life complicated. A date is a number stored in excel. Why are you changing system defaults of your windows/mac, let it be what it is. you just use the formula as stated above by experts.

Comment: No need to share this data in a comment, since the problem really is how Excel has auto-converted your input. The top row is now (most likely) a mixture of string and numeric. String where Excel could **not** auto-convert a string that looked like a data, and numeric where Excel **could** recognize a pattern, e.g. 1/9/23 was converted allbeit it being the wrong actual date. Start dealing with this problem at the entree level of this data first. Make sure that it's imported as strings first.

Comment: ok so I will focus on the header, thank you for your support

Comment: I just copied the dates posted in comments and used `Text To Columns` to make those text looking dates as excel dates and change the column formatting as `DMY` instead of `MDY` and it works. clearly. Also this is a onetime operation and nt dynamic.